# How to set up Ruby installation for users of Jekyll who don't know Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, debugging, installation, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll for my `gh-pages`-based website, but I am not a Ruby developer. I have been trying for a while now to set up my Ruby installation in such a way that standard Jekyll operations "just work" without errors or warnings but I cannot seem to get it right.

I did a fresh install of Ruby and Jekyll and yet I keep running into countless problems. As soon as one of them is fixed another appears, and so I think there must be something fundamentally wrong in the way I set things up. I used RVM to install Ruby to keep it separate from the system installation.

`which ruby` returns `/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby`
`which Jekyll` returns `/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/jekyll`

Currently, I am fighting with `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension` following `bundle install`. This appears after `Installing yajl-ruby 1.2.1 with native extensions.

However, rather than just a solution for this specific issue, I would like to know more generally what are the things one should pay attention to when using Ruby and Jekyll on a Mac, because just following the instructions on `jekyllrb.com` gives me the impression that this is highly highly problematic and error-prone (which I am sure is really just my mistake). Only about half of the Jekyll templates I have tried build at all (albeit always with some sort of warning of the type `Ignoring posix-spawn-0.3.13 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine posix-spawn --version 0.3.13`). The other half just fail altogether.

I apologise if my question is a little helpless, but I really know nothing about the Ruby ecosystem; I just want to get Jekyll to work. Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I have set up a website for people who want to use Jekyll without touching the command-line, called [Jekyll Codex](http://jekyllcodex.org). You might want to check that out.

Using [CloudCannon](http://cloudcannon.com/) will enable you to work on your Jekyll project from any machine in the world without installing ANYTHING. Note that CloudCannon has a free tier, but they are not very clear about that.

Another option is to use [Cloud9](https://c9.io/), which is also free. They have online/virtual Linux environments. You can also work from anywhere, but you need to install Jekyll yourself. This is a piece of cake on Linux. Note that this solution will give you much better build times than CloudCannon, but is more complex (on the bright-side: it will make you feel like a pro).

Comment: I understand that these are alternative hosting solutions. I work with GitHub a lot and would like to host my Jekyll page there. I was hoping there is a relatively straightforward way to avoid the most common pitfalls when setting up Ruby and Jekyll locally. I'm not afraid of the command line. I simply don't know any Ruby.

Comment: Please note that these are NOT alternative hosting solutions. You can still host on Github Pages and use git. These are ways to run Jekyll in the cloud, instead of trying to install Jekyll locally on your very expensive and bad performing Linux clone (just messing with you). Where you host is totally up to you. I am only trying to help you run Jekyll 'the easy way'. The easy way is preinstalled (CloudCannon) or on Linux (Cloud9). Good luck!

Comment: Understood. I followed the instructions on Jekyll Codex, but when CloudCannon pushes the site to GitHub, GitHub tries to compile it and fails. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please ask a new question and put a link to your repo and the error message in it. Then I/we would love to look at it.